# download pdf with knitr in shiny in R

Tags: r, pdf, download, shiny, knitr

I try to create button for downloading with knitr package. 
I have found some example which works a bit but I'm not able to change the name of the pdf. moreover it causes errors then. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/piNHe.png)

second problem is that when I download the file , it is not a .pdf extension and I have to choose program to open it when I try to open. How can I download file as .pdf in default?

here are my codes (example from the internet):

server.R

```
library(knitr)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
output$myreport = downloadHandler(

filename = "adads.pdf",

content = function(file) {
  out = knit2pdf('input.Rnw', clean = TRUE )
  file.rename(out, file) # move pdf to file for downloading
},

contentType = 'application/pdf'
 )
 })
```

ui.R

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(basicPage(
 textInput('firstname', 'First name', value = 'Jimmy'),
 textInput('lastname', 'Last name', value = 'John'),
 downloadButton('myreport')
))
```

and  input.Rnw file

```
 \documentclass{article}

 \begin{document}

 <<names>>=
 input$firstname
 input$lastname
    @

 \end{document}
```

Comment: I've tried your code and it works perfectly. What is the error you're talking about?

Comment: did you obtain file called "adads.pdf" ? why my name is still 'myreport' and without .pdf?   use exactly what I pasted here

Comment: I used exactly your code and I obtained "adads.pdf", yes. What is the error you're talking about ?

Comment: ok,,, I see now that it just doesn't work in the Rstudio but works in the browser... hehh... sorry and thanks. i will delete that topic in hours

Comment: Ah yes I see. Many things do not work in the RStudio browser.